# how long would it take to brute force an 8 character string vs. a 32 character string

Tags: security, brute-force

How long would it take to brute force a 32 character string.

Assuming you have a web page that tells you whether the string is valid, and there is no limit to the number of requests.

I'm using a 32 character string in a password reset link emailed to the user, and I'm wondering what the time difference would be to try all 32 characters vs. trying an 8 character string.

Are we talking minutes, hours, days, months?

Comment: Shouldn't matter. Implement a three strikes rule. If they are that lucky they should stop trying to crack you and buy a lottery ticket. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate this we would need the number of characters in the set and the number of attempts per second.

If we assume that you have 100000 attempts per second and 64 characters in the set this is how it would look:

```
64^8 / 100000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 32 days

64^32 / 100000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = approx. 7.2E47 days
```

Answer (score 0):

that depends on the charset, aka how many legal characters there are for each of your 8 characters.

Rest assured that the number of permutations grows exponentially!

Comment: This isn't about permutations, it's about Cartesian products.

Comment: In mathematics, the notion of permutation is used with several slightly different meanings, all related to the act of permuting (rearranging) objects or values. Call it what you will Dr. larsmans ;)